# estimating a solution to a linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on a word-problem which basically boils down to the equation $x/a + x/b = 1$ where $a$ and $b$ are both positive (a is smaller than b).

Of course, I know how to solve this equation exactly, but based on the word-problem I found out that you can get a reasonable estimate on its solution if you take the minimum of $a$ and $b/2$ and average that out with $a/2$.

Is this always a good estimate? Can it be derived from the equation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question: we have the equation $$\frac xa+\frac xb=1\iff x=\frac{ab}{a+b}\ldots$$ You've *the exact* solution (assuming $\;a\neq -b\;$ , of course) so what in the world do you need "a estimation" for??

Comment: I don´t need it. I am just curious if it works.

Comment: Ok, I see...now, what do you mean by "average out by a/2"? Do you mean dividing by a/2 ?

Comment: no, (min(a,b/2) + a/2) /2

Comment: for example a = 40 and b=60, then the estimate would be (20+30)/2

Comment: see my answer now, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so only for curiosity. If I understood accurately what you say, you are doing

$$x\cong \frac{\min\{a\,,\,b/2\}+a/2}2$$

But we know we the actual value of $\;x\;$ , so we're asking whether

$$\frac{ab}{a+b}\cong\frac{\min\{a\,,\,b/2\}+a/2}2$$

But if $\;a>>b\;$ , say $\;a=10,000\;,\;b=1\;$ , then we get

$$0.999900009...\frac{10,000}{10,001}=x\ncong\frac{\frac12+5,000}2=2,500.25$$

Comment: Interesting, it seems the estimate breaks down if there is a big difference between a an b.

Comment: Well, yes. If $\;a\cong b\;$ ,then $$\frac{ab}{a+b}\cong\frac{a^2}{2a}=\frac a2$$ and also $$\frac{\min\{a,b/2\}+a/2}2\cong \frac{a/2\,+\,a/2}2=\frac a2\ldots$$